# AudoiDeviceGetCurrentTime: no deivce with given ID error in xcode

Tags: xcode

I keep getting this error again and again.

where can I check to fix this?

AudioDeviceGetCurrentTime: no device with given ID

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: same here, same issue

Comment: same issue here. running iOS 16.0 on iPad simulator 12.9